# Thumbnail Checkboxes

Tags: c#, .net, checkbox, user-controls, custom-controls

I'm looking for a .Net control for one of my latest projects.

Essentially I need a thumbnail checkbox, or an image checkbox.

In fact, this screenshot from inside windows shows EXACTLY what I want.

[image: Thumbnail CheckBox]

Does anyone know of a control I can download somewhere with this functionality? If not, I can make a custom control, but that's much more involved and kind of a pain. I'll do it if I must, but I'd have trouble getting started on that too.

Thanks.

EDIT: This is for WPF apps. AKA Xaml.

Comment: you need a usercontrol with a PictureBox and CheckBox. not so hard

Comment: Have alook at the finished solution with padding and a drop shadow!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would you believe it : All you need is a single, regular `CheckBox`!

Its `BackgroundImage` has `Zoom` capability and with a few lines you can pimp it up to look pretty cool. The first row is the original method; in the second row you can see the effect of the hoverImage function: The images are padded and have a drop shadow:

[image]

Here is the function to create it:

```
CheckBox imageCheckBox(Image img, Size size, string name)
{
    CheckBox cbx = new CheckBox();

    cbx.AutoSize = false;
    cbx.Text = "";
    cbx.CheckAlign = ContentAlignment.TopLeft;
    cbx.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom;
    cbx.Size = size;
    cbx.BackgroundImage = img;
    cbx.Name = name;
    cbx.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3, 3, 0, 0);
    cbx.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;

    cbx.CheckedChanged += (s, e) =>
    {
      cbx.BackColor = cbx.Checked ? SystemColors.Control : SystemColors.Window;
    };

    cbx.MouseEnter += (s, e) =>
    {
       cbx.BackColor = cbx.Checked ? SystemColors.GradientActiveCaption :      
                                     SystemColors.GradientInactiveCaption;
    };

    cbx.MouseLeave += (s, e) =>
    {
      cbx.BackColor = cbx.Checked ? SystemColors.Control : SystemColors.Window;
    };

    cbx.Paint += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (cbx.ClientRectangle.Contains(cbx.PointToClient(Cursor.Position))  
        ||  cbx.Checked))
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.DarkGray, 0, 0,cbx.Width-1,cbx.Height-1);
    };

    return cbx;
}
```

Add a `FlowLayoutPanel` to your project and call it like this:

```
size = new Size(200, 80);
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(imageCheckBox(yourImage1, size, "checkBox1"));
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(imageCheckBox(yourImage2, size, "checkBox2"));
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(imageCheckBox(yourImage3, size, "checkBox3"));
```

Depending on how you want to acces them later you may want to keep references to the `CheckBoxes` in maybe a `Dictionary` before you add them to the `FLP`, to access them by `Name`.

I have added a little style by coding the `CheckedChanged`,  `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events and by adding a border in a conditional `Paint` event..

The result is already pretty good. To mimick the padding and the stylish drop shadow you can use this function:

```
Bitmap hoverImage(Image img, Size size, Padding pad)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height);
    // client rectangle
    Rectangle cRect = new Rectangle(pad.Left, pad.Top, 
         size.Width - pad.Left - pad.Right, size.Height - pad.Top - pad.Bottom);
    // image proportion
    float fi = 1f * img.Width / img.Height;
    // target size
    int nw = fi >= 1 ? cRect.Width : (int)(1f * cRect.Width / fi);
    int nh = (int)(1f * nw / fi);
    if (nh > cRect.Height)
    {
        nh = cRect.Height;
        nw = (int)(1f * nh * fi);
    }
    Size nSize = new Size(nw, nh);
    Point dPoint = new Point(pad.Left + (cRect.Width - nw) / 2, 
                             pad.Top + (cRect.Height - nh) / 2);

    using ( Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp) )
    {
        Rectangle dRect = new Rectangle(dPoint, nSize);
        Rectangle sRect = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, img.Size);
        Rectangle shRect = new Rectangle(dRect.X - 3, dRect.Y - 3, 
                                         dRect.Width + 8, dRect.Height + 8);
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(i * 15, Color.Black))) 
                    G.DrawRectangle(pen, shRect);
            shRect.Inflate(-1, -1);
        }
        G.DrawImage(img, dRect, sRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }
    return bmp;
}
```

Change this in the `imageCheckBox` code:

```
// cbx.BackgroundImage = img;
   cbx.BackgroundImage =  hoverImage( img, size,new Padding(10, 10, 10, 10) ) ;
```

And as we are ceating a fresh Bitmap add a Disposed event along with the other events to clean up the GDI resources:

```
cbx.Disposed += (s, e) => { 
    if (cbx.BackgroundImage != null) cbx.BackgroundImage.Dispose(); };
```

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you! I'm going to make a custom control out of it and will post when I'm done! Thanks!!!

Comment: Well, it looks like I left out a critical piece of information... this control is intended for a WPF app. Definitely my fault as I didn't tag or specify it as such, but that problem became abundantly clear once I started toying with your code. Nevertheless, I'll see if I can't modify it for a WPF environment. You have given me a great head start.

Comment: Ouch! For WPF I would expect the best solution will be pretty much __totally different__! Things like a drop shadow come rather easy there and most controls are created by combining various components.. So I doubt that my code will really be of much use there.. Since the question is closed you won't get a WPF answer now. Maybe you should post a new question; in order not to get it closed again you should try to code first and post the result in your question. Clearly you won't need a ready-made control. Asking for that is seen as asking for tool or library, which is off-topic..